# behind or ahead?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, late-modern-english

The following is an extract from *Frankenstein* by Mary Shelley. I'm wondering whether the word "behind" is equal to "ahead" in 21st-century English in this context.

> Justine died; she rested; and I was alive. The blood flowed freely in my veins, but a weight of despair and remorse pressed on my heart, which nothing could remove. Sleep fled from my eyes; I wanderedlike an evil spirit, for I had committed deeds of mischief beyond description horrible, and more, much more (I persuaded myself), was yet **behind**. Yet my heart overflowed with kindness, and the love of virtue.

Answer (score 4):

The quote seems to be in error, until you check a [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behind):

"8. (archaic) Not yet brought forward, produced, or exhibited to view; out of sight; remaining."

"Yet to be revealed", "yet to come", or as you suggested "ahead", would make more sense in modern English.

Comment: I find this use of "behind" rather interesting, because it can be rendered as "ahead," its opposite, in current English.